# A question related to abelian extensions

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $K/F$ be an abelian extension (a Galois extension $K/F$ such that $Gal(K/F)$ is abelian) of degree at least $2$.

Prove that there exists a tower of fields $F=K_{0} \subset K_1 \subset \cdots \subset K_r=K$ such that $K_{i+1}/{K_i}$ is a Galois extension of prime degree (i.e. $[K_{i+1}:K_i]=p$, where $p$ is prime) for each $i$.

How do I prove this claim? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If it is finite, then just use the corresponding result about abelian groups and the Galois correspondence.

Comment: And note that since $K/F$ is Abelian, every subgroup of $Gal(K/F)$ is normal.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!